# Laravel OBSERVER update process

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, observer-pattern, observers

*In SESSObServer*

```php
public function updated(SESS $sESS)
{
    log::info("data updated");
    if ($sESS->wasChanged('is_active')) {
        log::info("data updated");
    }
}
```

IN Observer, created(SESS $sESS) function run but update is not run. How can i solve problem ?

I changed my query. Now, this is run.
I didn't use get. I used first()

```
 $sess = SESS::where('sess_id', request('id'))->first();
        $sess->save();
```

Comment: You may register observers in the `boot` method of your application's `App\Providers\EventServiceProvider` service provider.

Comment: public function boot()
    {
        SESS::observe(SESSObServer::class);
    }

I write this in EventServiceProvider

Comment: You have `$sESS` not `$sESSIONS`. Btw, I love your `unCLEARCasE`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your `Observer` is registered.

```php
# app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php
use App\Models\SESS;
use App\Observers\SESSObserver;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        SESS::observe(SESSObServer::class);
    }
}
```

2. Make sure you're using the correct classes. The logger's class is `Log` (capital `L`)

```php
public function updated(SESS $sESS)
{
    Log::info("data updated");
    if ($sESS->wasChanged('is_active')) {
        Log::info("data updated");
    }
}
```

Alternatively, I think you can still use `info()`.

```php
public function updated(SESS $sESS)
{
    info("data updated");
    if ($sESS->wasChanged('is_active')) {
        info("data updated");
    }
}
```

3. If you're using apache, make sure the apache user can write to the log file.